# Why $S^1$ not homotopic to a point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Why $S^1$ is not homotopic to a point?

Why $H(r,t)=(r\cos2\pi t,r\sin2\pi t)$ dose not give homotopy between $S^1$ and $0$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: To which set does $(r,t)$ belong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the domain and codomain of your $H$? A function requires three ingredients: domain, codomain and formula. You've only provided a formula.

So what is $S^1$? Typically it is defined as

$$S^1=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ \lVert v\rVert=1\}$$

Now what does it mean for $S^1$ to be homotopic to a point? I assume you mean "homotopy equivalent" to a point. And this means there are two functions
$$f:S^1\to \{0\}$$
$$g:\{0\}\to S^1$$

such that $g\circ f:S^1\to S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to the identity map $id:S^1\to S^1$. And $f\circ g$ is homotopy equivalent to the identity, but in this case this is always satisfied. You did not provide an example of that.

---

There is another way to look at it. If we can find a point in $S^1$ such that $S^1$ deformation retracts onto it, then $S^1$ is homotopic to a point. I think this is what you mean by your $H(r,t)=\big(r\cos(2\pi t),r\sin(2\pi t )\big)$ function. However note that $H(0,t)=(0,0)$ does not belong to $S^1$. Your $H$ goes outside of $S^1$ and so it is not a well defined function.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is a homotopy between the unit circle in the plane and the origin.

Whether or not two subsets are homotopic depends on the ambient space. For example, in the plane, the unit circle is homotopic to a point, but not in the punctured plane ${\bf R}^2-\{0\}$. The puncture can be thought of as an obstacle.

By "a circle is not homotopic to a point", we mean that a circle is not contractable (homotopy equivalent to a point); i.e. each point in the circle is driven to a single point P through a path that lies entirely in the circle, and nearby points move on "neighboring" paths.

It is not possible for a circle and a point because they have different fundamental groups.